# Page not found (404) Request Method: GET Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/signup in DJANGO even though urls is mapped correctly

Tags: python, html, django, server, pgadmin

Below is the **urls.py** file of sub-app accounts

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views 

urlpatterns = [
    path("signup",views.signup,name='signup')
   
]
```

This **views.py** of accounts

```
def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':

        firstname = request.POST['first_name']
        lastname = request.POST['last_name']
        username = request.POST['username']
        password1 = request.POST['password1']
        password2 = request.POST['password2']
        email = request.POST['email']

        if password1==password2:
                user = User.objects.create_user(firstname =first_name ,lastname =last_name ,username =username , email=email, password=password1)
                user.save();
                print("USER CREATED SUCCESSFULLY")
                return redirect('login.html')
    else:
        return redirect('signup.html')
```

I have even mapped the url in main url.py also, but still it is showing error.
below is the signup.html

The **signup.html** file

```
<form action="signup" method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <input type="text" name="first_name" placeholder="FIRST NAME"><br>
            <input type="text" name="last_name" placeholder="LAST NAME"><br>
            <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="USERNAME"><br>
            <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="EMAILID"><br>
            <input type="password" name="password1" placeholder="PASSWORD"><br>
            <input type="password" name="password2" placeholder="CONFIRM PASSWORD"><br>
            <input type="submit">
```

**can anyone please help me out with this problem, i am not getting what went wrong.**
It is displaying page not found error.

Comment: is the terminal running correctly, without any errors? and did you perform the makemigrations and migrate steps ?

Comment: @AvinMathew Yeah! Terminals are working absolutely fine without any errors and i even tried makemigrations and migrate, it is not working. The problem it is showing page not found even though the url is correctly mapped. And i have included this name in setting.py also.

Answer (score 0):

you need to include accounts.urls in project urls.py (i.e.,) which folder contains settings.py

for example:
let i am assumed that you create project Todo

```
Todo    
 - accounts
    - __init__.py
    - models.py
    - urls.py
    - views.py
    - apps.py
    - tests.py

 - Todo
    - __init__.py
    - urls.py
    - wsgi.py
    - settings.py
```

Todo/urls.py
you need to include accounts.urls

```
from django.conf.urls import include, path
app_name = "Todo"

urlpatterns = [
    # Examples:
     path(r'^accounts/', include('accounts.urls', namespace="Account")),
]
```

you need to accounts apps in file **settings.py** application definition list

```
# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'accounts',
     ......
    'django.contrib.auth',
]
```

Comment: I have included all this, these things are mentioned properly. But not getting what is going wrong.